# sbt: How can I add a local filesystem jar to my project?

Tags: jar, repository, sbt

I have a library compiled to a jar (not an sbt project, just the jar file) that's not available on a repository.

Is there a simple way to add a reference to the jar in the filesystem/project directly?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

You can put the jar in your project's lib folder (create it if it doesn't exist), it will then appear on your project's unmanaged-classpath.

To publish a jar file locally, if you have an sbt project that produces the jar, it should be as simple as invoking "publish-local" to publish the jar to your local ivy repository so that you can use that jar in another one of your projects (on the same computer).

Comment: Thanks Fred!  Do you by chance know the answer to the first question (how to publish a jar file locally?)

Comment: Updated my answer, sorry about the short original answer, wrote that on my phone while away from my computer :)

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear.  I was already aware of the publish-local command, but I only have the jar file, not an sbt project.  Do you know of a way to accomplish the same thing with just a jar file?

Comment: Last comment: You only have to create a folder called lib in the project, and put the jar there. That's all. Additionally, to make it work in eclipse, for example, you have to add the jar to the classpath.

Comment: Just to be clear - we add the lib folder under /main/scala, not /main or /main/scala-<version>, correct?

Comment: `publish-local` seems to now be `publishLocal`, so the command `sbt publishLocal` did what I needed, cheers

Answer (score 44):

Your SBT project should be structured like this:

```
README.md
build.sbt
project/
src/
target/
```

Create a `lib/` directory to add a JAR file (e.g. `spark-daria_2.11-0.2.0.jar`) to the project:

```
README.md
build.sbt
lib/
  spark-daria_2.11-0.2.0.jar
project/
src/
target/
```

The location of the `lib/` directory should line-up with the output of the `sbt "show unmanagedBase"` command.

Refresh the project in your IDE and import the code just like you would import an external dependency.

```
import com.github.mrpowers.spark.daria.sql.DataFrameValidator
```

Comment: Hi, how can I add it to a subproject in .sbt declared as `Project(id = "core", base = file("core"))`?

Answer (score 3):

If you have multi-module project you should:

1. add lib to module dir (not to root). E.g., if you have module `core`, you should add jar to `core/lib`.
2. remove explicit dependency for specified jar in your build.sbt (or in another place). E.g., remove `libraryDependencies += <your jar in lib>`

Comment: About removing the libraryDependencies, does including "provided" instead of removing it cause the same effect?

Comment: I don't checked it, but it may be. I think in case of `provided` your assembly will not include libs from `lib` directory, which commonly, IMHO, is not good.