# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J

Tags: java, scala, opencv, intellij-idea, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm new to **openCV**, I want to use openCV in **Intellij IDEA (Scala)** to detect image blurriness.

I'm using library dependency **openpnp-opencv**

Here is versions detail.

Ubuntu version **22.04.3 LTS**

scala version **12.13.1**

sbt version **1.9.6**

here is my **build.sbt**

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.4"
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "FaceRecognitionAndComparison"
  )
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.openpnp" % "opencv" % "4.5.1-1")
```

here is my **FaceRecognition.scala**

```
import org.opencv.core.{Core, CvType, Mat, MatOfDouble}
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc

object FaceRecognition extends App {

  def isImageBlurry(imagePath: String): Boolean = {
    val image: Mat = Imgcodecs.imread(imagePath)

    val grayImage: Mat = new Mat()
    Imgproc.cvtColor(image, grayImage, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    val laplacian: Mat = new Mat()
    Imgproc.Laplacian(grayImage, laplacian, CvType.CV_64F)

    println(laplacian)

    val meanStdDevResult: MatOfDouble = new MatOfDouble()

    val stdDev: Double = meanStdDevResult.toArray()(1)

    val threshold: Double = 100.0

    stdDev < threshold
  }

  System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME)

  val imagePath = "/home/Pictures/Screenshots/Screenshot.png"

  if (isImageBlurry(imagePath)) {
    println("The image is blurry.")
  } else {
    println("The image is not blurry.")
  }
}
```

Build unfortunately got an error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(Ljava/lang/String;)J
    at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread_1(Native Method)
    at org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs.imread(Imgcodecs.java:320)
    at FaceRecognition$.isImageBlurry(FaceRecognition.scala:65)
```

what I have tried is to **download and install openCV** from it's official website which is https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d7/d9f/tutorial_linux_install.html.

After that I added following lines in my code to load **jar** file `System.load("/home/build/bin/opencv-480.jar")` **but this didn't resolve my issue**.

Then I added jar file in project module (**file -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Click on plus -> add opencv-480.jar -> apply -> OK**), this time I got an error which is

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java470 in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib64, /lib64, /lib, /usr/lib]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2662)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:827)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1871)
    at FaceRecognition$.delayedEndpoint$FaceRecognition$1(FaceRecognition.scala:83)
```

Guide me how can I resolve this error and implement openCV in (Intellij IDEA) scala.

Comment: Why do you use `System.load("/home/build/bin/opencv-480.jar")`? You should either add sbt dependency or add the lib to lib directory in the project folder, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733028/sbt-how-can-i-add-a-local-filesystem-jar-to-my-project

Comment: You may take a look at this file: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv-examples/blob/master/OpenCV_Cookbook/build.sbt

The exception is not about Java, but they can't find some native libraries (written in C/C++) like opencv_java470.so, etc, it will put them under the OS's PATH env. You should let SBT install the whole dependencies.