# How to add external jar files in build.sbt in intellij idea?

Tags: java, scala, opencv, intellij-idea, sbt

I was trying to use openCV in Intellij Idea **(scala)**, for that I've downloaded openCV from their official website - and after installing openCV I got **opencv-480.jar** file in **build/bin**. For installation I have done **(in Ubuntu)**:

```
$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y cmake g++ wget unzip
$ wget -O opencv.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.x.zip
$ unzip opencv.zip
$ mkdir -p build && cd build
$ cmake ../opencv-4.x
$ make -j4
$ sudo make install
```

Then I've opened my Intellij Idea and performed following steps:

1. Go to **(file -> project structure -> modules)**
2. Clicked on **+** sign
3. Selected **(library -> java)**
4. Selected that **opencv-480.jar**
5. Clicked on **apply** and then **ok**

Above steps added jar file. Then I added library path by doing:

1. Go to **(file -> project structure -> libraries)**
2. Clicked on recently added library **(opencv-480)**
3. Then in right panel, I clicked on **+** sign
4. Selected **lib** folder which I got after installation of openCV

After all above, now I'm able to access and use openCV in my scala project.

But the problem is whenever I **clean** the project and **run** in **sbt-shell**, it **removes** that jar file from project structure. Now I want to add that **external jar file** and setting of **lib folder path** via **build.sbt** - but I'm not able to find any help on this.

**Guide me how can I add external jar file and use it as dependency in build.sbt.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sbt: How can I add a local filesystem jar to my project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7733028/sbt-how-can-i-add-a-local-filesystem-jar-to-my-project)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved above issue. What I've done is:

1. Made a **opencv_lib** folder in root.
2. Put **opencv-480.jar** file in this **opencv_lib** folder.
3. Made another **native_libs** folder inside **opencv_lib** folder.
4. Put files of **lib** folder **(which I got after installing opencv)** into that **native_libs** folder.

Then at last added some lines in **build.sbt**, my project's **build.sbt** is:

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.4"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "OpenCV-Check"
  )

run / fork := true

unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / "opencv_lib"

val openCVNativeLibPath = file("opencv_lib/native_libs")

run / javaOptions += s"-Djava.library.path=${openCVNativeLibPath.getAbsolutePath}"
```

Then I build the project and it worked for me.

https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Dependencies.html

Above linked helped me. Thanks to **Gael J** for that link.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a ["unmanaged dependency"](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Library-Dependencies.html) in SBT by **putting the JAR in the `lib` folder and everything will be automatic**.

There are also other ways documented in the link above for more complex scenarios.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!                                                                                                        I've tried above and used (unmanagedBase := baseDirectory.value / "lib") but it is only adding jar file and giving me (Exception in thread "sbt-bg-threads-1" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java480 in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib64, /lib64, /lib, /usr/lib])

Comment: Even I've tried to set the path of lib folder (which I get after installation of opencv), using (javaOptions += s"-Djava.library.path=/home/zaryab/IdeaProjects/OpenCV-Check/lib") but it is not setting the path and giving same error.